# Translate addresses on stack to the exported function names

Tags: debugging

I'm investigating a bug that happens in proprietary DLL that doesn't have PDB symbols.

The callstack looks like this:

```
KernelBase.dll!7710c54f()
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for KernelBase.dll]    
msvcr90.dll!__CxxThrowException@8()
ScrUsSsDtceLib.dll!5ec92ef1()
ScrUsSsDtceLib.dll!5ec91ec4()
ScrUsSsDtceLib.dll!5ec96f86()
ScrUsSsDtceLib.dll!5ec9de1c()
ScrUsSsDtceLib.dll!5ec9d5f5()
ScrUsSsDtceLib.dll!5ecc2f5d()
vcomp90.dll!_vcomp::ParallelRegion::HandlerThreadFunc(void *,unsigned long)
vcomp90.dll!_vcomp::NullAPCFunc(unsigned long)
kernel32.dll!759b336a()
ntdll.dll!777e9902()
ntdll.dll!777e98d5()
```

Also I see the following DLL exports in Dependency Walker.

```
Ordinal Hint    Entry Point Function
1   0   0x000135D0  IScrUsDtce2D::IScrUsDtce2D(void)
2   1   0x00013B30  IScrUsDtce3D::IScrUsDtce3D(void)
3   2   0x00013F50  IScrUsDtce2D::~IScrUsDtce2D(void)
4   3   0x00013B50  IScrUsDtce3D::~IScrUsDtce3D(void)
5   4   0x00012AA0  class IScrUsDtce2D & IScrUsDtce2D::operator=(class IScrUsDtce2D const &)
6   5   0x00012AD0  class IScrUsDtce3D & IScrUsDtce3D::operator=(class IScrUsDtce3D const &)
7   6   0x000139A0  int IScrUsDtce2D::FilterImage(unsigned short const *,unsigned short *,int,int)
8   7   0x00013DC0  int IScrUsDtce3D::FilterVolume(int,unsigned char const * const *,unsigned char * *,int)
9   8   0x00013620  int IScrUsDtce2D::Init(char const *,struct UsDtceImgInfo const &,enum IScrUsDtce2D::ProcType,unsigned short const *)
10  9   0x00013BA0  int IScrUsDtce3D::Init(char const *,struct UsDtceImgInfo const &,enum IScrUsDtce3D::ProcType)
11  10  0x000137F0  int IScrUsDtce2D::InitSSC(char const *,struct UsDtceImgInfo const &,enum IScrUsDtce2D::ProcType,unsigned short const *,bool,float *,int)
```

Is there any way to understand which functions are called?

UPD: I understand that bigger part of the callstack addresses may be private functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

post unadulterated stack use kb and paste the exact output
it is kinda difficult to understand what the symbols are in the stack paste
if they are return address ebp , args ?

most of the time you may need a disassembler application like ida / radare2 etc that does some extra work to analyze function boundaries and possibly name them

for example this is a stack from livekd.exe from sysinternals

```
0:002> ~0kb
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
00 0021eab0 77546a64 7570179c 000000cc 00000000 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
01 0021eab4 7570179c 000000cc 00000000 00000000 ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xc
02 0021eb20 76bebaf3 000000cc ffffffff 00000000 KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x98
03 0021eb38 76bebaa2 000000cc ffffffff 00000000 kernel32!WaitForSingleObjectExImplementation+0x75
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for e:\sysint\livekd.exe
04 0021eb4c 00076038 000000cc ffffffff 00000000 kernel32!WaitForSingleObject+0x12
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
05 0021fae8 000795e6 00000001 002fbec0 002fbee8 livekd+0x6038
06 0021fb30 76bf3c45 7ffdf000 0021fb7c 775637eb livekd+0x95e6
07 0021fb3c 775637eb 7ffdf000 770c043e 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
08 0021fb7c 775637be 00079663 7ffdf000 00000000 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x70
09 0021fb94 00000000 00079663 7ffdf000 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b
```

you can find where livekd is loaded with

```
0:002> lm m live*
Browse full module list
start    end        module name
00070000 0010d000   livekd     (no symbols)
```

now assume you load it in radare2 with the same base address **0x70000** you can seek to the return address in stack **0x76038**

radare does some analysis and says this address belongs to main()

```
radare2 -B 0x70000 -AA e:\SYSINT\livekd.exe

[0x00079663]> s 0x76038

[0x00076038]> pd 5
|           0x00076038      6860894200     push 0x428960
|           0x0007603d      ffd6           call esi
|           0x0007603f      6860894200     push 0x428960
|           0x00076044      c705c47b4200.  mov dword [0x427bc4], 0     ; [0x427bc4:4]=-1
|           0x0007604e      ff158c704100   call dword [0x41708c]
[0x00076038]> afn

main <-------------
[0x00076038]>
```

another example

```
[0x00076038]> s 0x795e6
[0x000795e6]> afn
entry0  <----------------
[0x000795e6]>
```